# DevTest Labs Virtual Machine Auto-start

Tags: azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devtest-labs

Is there a way to enable the Auto-start feature on a DevTest Labs virtual machine as part of the creation i.e. can it be added to the VM's ARM template?

I enable this manually via the Azure portal currently, but I'm finding that it gets disabled when subsequent deployments from Team Services are made.

**Solution**

Inspired by the accepted answer from Ashok below, I've managed to tweak and simplify the PowerShell script to the following...

```
Param([string] $resourceId)

$tags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $resourceId).Tags

if (-Not ($tags) -Or -Not($tags.ContainsKey('AutoStartOn'))) {
  $tags += @{ AutoStartOn=$true; }
}

if (-Not ($tags) -Or -Not($tags.ContainsKey('AlwaysOn'))) {
  $tags += @{ AlwaysOn=$true; }
}

Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $resourceId -Tag $tags -Force
```

Comment: How do you subsequent deployments from Team Services?

Comment: As part of the release definition in Team Services, we use the **DevTest Labs Create VM** task to ensure the machine is available before deployemnt. I can only assume this process is what is causing the machines to lose their **auto-start** tag. Maybe due to the ARM template supplied during VM creation? Perhaps there's another way to handle this such as the PowerShell in Ashok's answer below.

Comment: Could you get necessary information through Get-AzureRmResource command? `$VmResourceId = "subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourcegroups/$labResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/labs/$labName/virtualmachines/$VmName"
$vm = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $VmResourceId -ExpandProperties`